# Observing changes to DOM properties

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like to know when certain properties of an arbitrary object change.

I read the answer to this question: "[extend setter default object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821225/extend-setter-default-object)" which seemed to suggest the solution using getters and setters.  However, I tried to use it to trap changes to both the `id` and `style` properties of a DOM object and it did not work.  One strange thing I observed is that as soon as I create a setter for the `id` field is the original `id` field vanishes, so attempts to read or write the value fails.   As the property may be a DOM property, which sometimes aren't simple variables, I can't simply create my own variable as I can't arbitrarily re-create whatever underlying functionality is generating the value.

All I really want to do is detect when the property changes, and pass the change through transparently.

Some further research led me to this page [presenting a polyfill for Object.watch](https://gist.github.com/XoseLluis/4750176).  However, while this watch function appears to let me see when the properties of an object change, the actual properties wind up not being changed at all.

Comment: Try mutaton events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events although not cross browser.

Comment: @sabithpocker only works on attribute changes, not property changes

Comment: Can you provide an example scenario of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @sabithpocker I want to be one change on the page to trigger another change, when the function creating the second change has no knowledge of what might make the original change.

Comment: I would suggest you to update the question with a minimal example. I am confused if you are looking for some data binding or observer patterns or just watching DOM element's mutation. Hope someone helps, ill be leaving my desk now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes in attributes. This works well for DOM properties that get/set markup attributes. Compared to mutation events, mutation observers run long after the actual mutation, instead of immediately. I've read that mutation observers perform better than mutation events.

You also bring up the question of how to access the original getter/setter when you redefine a property. You won't need to worry about this if you use the mutation observer solution. In some browsers, such as Firefox, the original functionality of a property like `id` is also implemented as a getter/setter. For example, if you ran `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Element.prototype, 'id').set.call(myElement, 'asdf')`, it would be like `myElement.id = 'asdf'`, even if `myElement.id` were redefined. Some browsers don't do it this way. Chromium, for example, is [still working](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43394) on implementing [this aspect](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-attributes) of Web IDL.